# How to shuffle objects in JS

Tags: javascript, css, html

Currently working on a sliding-type game and am running into trouble with mainly my shuffle function. I'm trying to tweak the Fisher-Yates shuffle but am only familiar using that certain function with arrays. I figured it'd be easy enough to adapt it to objects outside of an array but don't believe I'm doing it right. Would also like to be able to reset all objects to original position on click of reset button.

```js
function scrambleBoard() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("b33") - 1; i++) {
    var x = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (document.getElementById("b33") - i));
    var temp = x;
    x = i;
    i = temp;
  }
  return x;
}

for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
  for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
    var bid = "b" + r + c;
    var val = 4 * r + c + 1;
    if (bid === "b33")
      val = ' ';
    var s = '<input type = "button" id = "' + bid + '" value = "' + val + '" onclick = "makeMove(this.id);" />' + '\n';
    document.write(s);
  }
}
```

```css
#b00 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b01 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b02 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 130px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b03 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b10 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b11 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b12 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 130px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b13 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b20 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b21 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b22 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 130px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b23 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 220px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b30 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b31 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 70px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b32 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 130px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#b33 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 280px;
  left: 190px;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
}
#btnReset {
  font-size: 12pt;
  position: absolute;
  top: 390px;
  left: 120px;
}
#btnScramble {
  font-size: 12pt;
  position: absolute;
  top: 390px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1> Slider Game </h1>
<input type="button" id="btnScramble" value="Scramble" onclick="scrambleBoard();" />
<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset Board" onclick="resetBoard();" />
```

Comment: Have you defined a stand-alone `getElementById()` function somewhere? Because that would throw an error otherwise, and applying arithmetics to an element wouldn't even make sense.

Comment: Thought that getElementById was used to call upon an object based off its id. New to the syntax if it's not obvious already.

Comment: It's `document.getElementById()`. Please open the browser's error console and fix the errors you see there before doing anything else. (And you probably want to add `.value` at the end there if you want the value of the input element and not the element itself.)

Comment: @Juhana ah that's it. Believe I've fixed the mistakes except I should add the .value to the element or variable x that I return?